MinGW missing _mingw.h
I'm currently trying to build an old project pulled from another computer on Simplicity Studio but I'm having a few issues. My first issue was missing windows.h in which I've downloaded MinGW to try and resolve it however, windows.h is missing a dependency _mingw.h
C:/mingw-w64-v11.0.0/mingw-w64-headers/include/windows.h:9:10: fatal error: _mingw.h: No such file or directory
This is where I downloaded the file from https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-release/mingw-w64-v11.0.0.tar.bz2/download
I think my issue is the computer that the project was in originally is on windows 10 and I'm porting it over a windows 11 PC so the MinGW is different from what I am currently using but that's besides the point.
I have tried commenting the library out from windows.h but something else is still calling for _mingw.h so I'm not really sure what to do.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

MinGW-w64 is more than just a bunch of headers. To use it typically you would use build tools built for/with MinGW-w64.
Standalone all-in-one releases of such tools are available from https://winlibs.com/
